# Update de dados SQLite Android

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Como pegar as informações que estão na tela e fazer um Update no banco de dados.

**Código que apresenta as informações nos EditText.**

```
public class DatabasesDAO extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static final String DATABASE = "baseteste";
private static final int VERSAO = 1;
private static final String TAG = "Teste";

private SQLiteDatabase db;

private ConfiguracoesSistema teste;

public DatabasesDAO(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE, null, VERSAO);
}


public Configuracao buscarConfiguracoes() {
    // Variável para utilizar a query no Cursor
    String sql = "select * from dj_tb_sis";
    // Objeto que recebe os registros do Banco de Dados
    Cursor cursor = getReadableDatabase().rawQuery(sql, null);
    // Instância do objeto que será retornado
    Configuracao configuracao = new Configuracao();

    // Carrega os atributos do Banco de Dados
    if (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        configuracao.setCodigoSistema(cursor.getLong(0));
        configuracao.setNomeEmpresa(cursor.getString(1));
        configuracao.setEnderecoEmpresa(cursor.getString(2));
        configuracao.setCidade(cursor.getString(3));
        configuracao.setTelefoneEmpresa(cursor.getString(4));
        configuracao.setCodigoEmpresa(cursor.getString(5));
        configuracao.setNumeroIP(cursor.getString(6));
        configuracao.setUsuarioFTP(cursor.getString(7));
        configuracao.setSenhaFTP(cursor.getString(8));
        configuracao.setPortaFTP(cursor.getString(9));
        configuracao.setCaminhoImportFTP(cursor.getString(10));
        configuracao.setCaminhoExportFTP(cursor.getString(11));
    }

    cursor.close();

    return configuracao;
}
```

Caso o usuário alterar alguma campo queria que ele já atualizasse no banco de dados.

**Código da minha Activity que apresenta os campos e o botão de atualizar dadas.**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.tela_configuracoes);

    razaoSocial = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtRazaoSocial);
    enderecoEmpresa = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtEndereco);
    cidade = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtCidade);
    telefoneEmpresa = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtTelefone);
    codigoEmpresa = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtQualEmpresa);
    numeroIP = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtEnderecoIP);
    usuarioFTP = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtUsuarioFTP);
    senhaFTP = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtSenhaFTP);
    portaFTP = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtPortaFTP);
    caminhoImportFTP = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtCaminhoImportar);
    caminhoExportFTP = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtCaminhoExportar);

    dao = new DatabasesDAO(this);

    Configuracao configuracao = dao.buscarConfiguracoes();
    razaoSocial.setText(configuracao.getNomeEmpresa().toString());
    enderecoEmpresa.setText(configuracao.getEnderecoEmpresa().toString());
    cidade.setText(configuracao.getCidade().toString());

    telefoneEmpresa.setText(configuracao.getTelefoneEmpresa().toString());
    codigoEmpresa.setText(configuracao.getCodigoEmpresa().toString());
    numeroIP.setText(configuracao.getNumeroIP().toString());
    usuarioFTP.setText(configuracao.getUsuarioFTP().toString());
    senhaFTP.setText(configuracao.getSenhaFTP().toString());
    portaFTP.setText(configuracao.getPortaFTP().toString());
    caminhoImportFTP.setText(configuracao.getCaminhoImportFTP().toString());
    caminhoExportFTP.setText(configuracao.getCaminhoExportFTP().toString());

    // Button btnAtualiza = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAtualizarDados);
}
```

**Aqui está o que tentei montar para fazer o Update.**

```
public int update(Configuracao config) throws Exception {
        SQLiteDatabase sqlLite = new DatabasesDAO(teste).getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues content = new ContentValues();

                content.put("t_nom_emp", config.getNomeEmpresa());
                content.put("t_end_emp", config.getEnderecoEmpresa());

                String where = "u_cod_sis = ?";

                String argumentos[] = { config.getNomeEmpresa() };

        return sqlLite.update("dj_tb_sis", content, where, argumentos);
    }
```

Comment: Tu queres fazer o update quando clicas num botão certo? Nessa altura tens de ir buscar os valores a view, porque eles não são atualizados na tua variável "configuracao" automáticamente.

Comment: Teria alguma dica de como eu começo esse método para poder buscara as informações e atribuir pro update?
Pelo que vi tenho que ter um where para o ID. Só que me enrolei todo aqui.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A forma de ir buscar a variável ao EditText dentro do evento que despoleta o update, por exemplo:

```
Button btnAtualiza;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

   ...
   btnAtualiza = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAtualizarDados);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    if (v == btnAtualiza) { //o teu botão de atualizar o formulário

         String razaoS = razaoSocial.getText().toString();

         ...
         update(/*variáveis*/);
    }        
}
```

Comment: O porque desse Validar?
Entendi como pegar o valor de dentro do EditText só não entendi o validar.

Comment: se tiveres mais que um botão, exemplo validar e cancelar, ele verifica se é o validar, editei vê o exemplo.

Comment: Continuo sem entender isso..
O que eu quero  é que nos campos EditText que tem informações, se ele acrescentar um letra qualquer, eu quero que quando clicar no botão Atualizar, ele pegue e atualize a linha no banco de dados..

Comment: Vou editar e por o teu exemplo, vê.

Comment: Olha só como está o meu
Activity
http://pastebin.com/embed_iframe.php?i=Fiapq1wc

BD
http://pastebin.com/embed_iframe.php?i=qWCgWuEM

Está me gerando o seguinte erro.
http://pastebin.com/embed_iframe.php?i=ET2AWj2V

Comment: Tens de inicializar a variável cfg, `Configuracao cfg = new Configuracao();`. Não sei como tens o construtor, mas é por ai.

Comment: Funcionou. Só que me parece que ele esta salvando um dado novo e não alterando. Porque quando reinicio a Activity ele me retorna ainda o valor inicial sem alteração.

Comment: Isso já pode ter a ver com o update. Faz um select * para ver o que tens guardado depois do update.

Comment: Jorge B. Funcionou, foi desatenção minha. Eu inicializei a Configurações duas vezes e eu não estava chamando o Busca.
cfg = dao.buscarConfiguracoes();

Comment: Deu tudo certo agora. Muito obrigado.